# How to write an initializer so it will only run when the database is set up correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer

I have an initializer that wants to fetch a variable from the database. This initialization is only needed when running the app with `rails server` or in production, as it is only used in the views.

```
config.default_country_id = Spree::Country.find_by(name: 'Netherlands').try(:id)
```

When running `rake db:setup` on a blank database (or any rake task) it fails, because the table where the value is being fetched does not exist (`db:setup` is trying to create it).

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'revitalised_staging.spree_countries' doesn't exist:...
```

How should I write such an initializer instead? Can I wrap it in some generic condition that allows me to skip it unless the database is setup correctly? Should I instead only run it when I know that will need it (i.e. whitelist a few commands or modes?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask ActiveRecord whether the table exists and set the option only if it does. I guess you can add some sort of fallback but since the value is used only in views, I wouldn't bother.

```
if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? Spree::Country.table_name
  config.default_country_id = Spree::Country.find_by(name: 'Netherlands').try(:id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
config.default_country_id = Spree::Country.find_by(name: 'Netherlands').try(:id) if defined?(Spree::Country)
```

should do the trick :-)

Ref: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/171753

Comment: AFAIK, `defined?(Spree::Country)` will return a "true-ish" value if the constant is defined, regardless of whether or not the table is existing.